# Regexp with prefix and constraints

Tags: regex, validation

I am trying to create a regular expression that does the following.

So I have a key with a matching value but there are some constraints on the key itself.
A key can have an **optional** key-prefix that is up to 253 characters while the normal key can be up to 63 characters. The key prefix is separated by a slash.

A key-prefix can also only have the following character set: `[a-z0-9A-Z\.]`
While the key part uses this following character set: `[a-z0-9A-Z\_\.\-]`

So this format

```
(key-prefix)/(key) : (value)
```

My problem is that I am not that great at regular expressions.. I've managed to solve the key part with the following

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}$
```

I know that I have to do something involving grouping in order to get the prefix. Something like this below but it stops matching when I try to add another group in.

```
(^[A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,252}$\/)?(^[A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}$)
```

Comment: Please provide a couple of test cases to see what exactly you want to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set regular expression as `(^[A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,252}\/[A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}$)` Please visit https://regex101.com/r/GBNe14/1 and try different combination.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. However, this regular expression only matches if the key-prefix is there. Anything that comes before the slash "/" if it's there should be optional. And if it is there, it should be 253 characters maximum

Comment: Okay @Lucas you can try this `(^([A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,252})?\/[A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}$)` and for experiment visit https://regex101.com/r/1JGj4X/1  and if you want exact 253 characters then set regex as `(^([A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{252})?\/[A-Za-z0-9][_0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}$)`

Comment: I gave it a go with the second one you suggested and moved things around a little bit. Thank you very much. I ended up with an expression that seems to cover my requirements :)